# cell width in a static UITableView

Tags: uitableview, static, width, cell

I'm using a UITableViewController with a static table view as options panel in my app. I have a background image which shows a rounded border panel and I would like to fit the static cells inside this image. Unfortunately it looks like it's not possible to set the cells width and that the table tries to get as much space as possible.

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot

Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

    //cell background image
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"];

    return cell;
}
```